# Alternative admin-side content browsing - module?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Does anyone know of, or is working on a Drupal 7 module which would provide alternative, hierarchical content browser on the admin side?

While the filter in the Find Content section is a great aid for unrelated pages, I'd really love to be able to browse through taxonomy-bound PAGES (rather than terms), just like I browse through folders and files in Windows Explorer or Mac's Finder.

What bites me most is that in default Drupal installation, the taxonomies are too much separated (in terms of managing and reviewing the content) from the actual pages. And the pages bound to vocabulary terms are browsable as unrelated ones.

I would be curious to see if anyone found a solution for that.
Regards,

Artur

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're looking for in the admin pages, but I do know that [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) is a great tool to build custom admin pages, especially when combined with [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

Comment: Imagine you have 200 pages, all bound to a taxonomy tree. What I want is to be able to view those pages in hierarchical style: by expanding/collapsing the parent nodes - just as much as hierarchical is the taxonomy tree. Is that more illustrative? :)